# re rendering using ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is there anyway I can force re-render a component using ref?

maybe something like this:

```
const CustomComp=React.memo(React.forwardRef(({...props},ref)=>{
  return(<View ref={ref} style={...}></View>);
}));

export default function App() {
  const Mainref=useRef();

  return(<View>
    <Pressable onPress={()=>{Mainref.TriggerRender()}}></Pressable>
    <CustomComp ref={Mainref}/>
  </View>);

}
```

that way if there are multiple sibling components with different refs
you wouldn't have to re-render all of them just to re-render one

is such a thing possible? or is there something similar to it?

Comment: Seems like it's possible that there's a different architectural way to solve this. For example, why would `CustomComp` re-render unless its data had changed? And if its data changed, it should re-render automatically. Maybe an XY problem?

Comment: Considering your previous question, this is definitely a XY problem. What are you trying to achieve with re-render? Why do you think re-render solves your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to re-render the child component.

```
const CustomComp=React.memo(React.forwardRef(({...props},ref)=>{
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  function onUpdate() {
    // will trigger re-render
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }
  // set onUpdate on mount
  React.useEffect(() => { 
    if (ref.current) ref.current.onUpdate = onUpdate;
  });
  return(<View ref={ref} style={...}></View>);
}));

export default function App() {
  let Mainref=useRef();

  return(<View>
    <Pressable onPress={()=>{Mainref.current.onUpdate()}}></Pressable>
    <CustomComp ref={Mainref}/>
  </View>);

}
```

Better approach is to lift the state to a level higher in the component tree, or use a global state manager such as React context API in case the state does not belong in the `App` component.

```
const CustomComp=React.memo(React.forwardRef(({...props},ref)=>{
  return(<View ref={ref} style={...}></View>);
}));

export default function App() {
  let Mainref=useRef();
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  function onUpdate() {
    // will trigger re-render on the whole view
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }

  return(<View>
    <Pressable onPress={onUpdate}></Pressable>
    <CustomComp ref={Mainref}/>
  </View>);

}
```